# Update/Delete wrong record because of ActiveRecord "type"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have 2 tables `Foo` and `FooArchive`, where `FooArchive` is a replica of `Foo`.  `FooArchive` is for storing old data from `Foo` in order to optimize and keep the first from growing too big.

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class FooArchive < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

`Foo` is subclassed:

```
class OneFoo < Foo
end

class TwoFoo < Foo
end
```

When I archive a record from `Foo` to `FooArchive` it also copies its `type`. When I get a record from `FooArchive` for example the last, once I get that record if I try to modify it like updating or deleting it will read the type and try to get the record from the `Foo` table instead of `FooArchive`.

```
foo_archive = FooArchive.last
SELECT `foo_archives`.* FROM `foo_archives` ORDER BY `foo_archives`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1

foo_archive.reload
SELECT `foos`.* FROM `foos` WHERE `foos`.`type` IN ('OneFoo') AND `foos`.`id` = 35 LIMIT 1
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find OneFoo with id=35 [WHERE `foos`.`type` IN ('OneFoo')]
```

I sort of understand why it is trying to find the record in the other table since the type belongs to that table.

Is there a way to make it work without modifying the data/columns, I'm thinking of getting rid of active record for this model but haven't found the way to do it.

In this case I'm using:

- Rails 3.2.21
- Ruby 2.1.4

Comment: Any reason that you're not mirroring `OneFoo` and `TwoFoo` and rewriting `type` when you copy rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails assumes your `FooArchive` model is using STI (Single Table Inheritance) to instantiate `OneFoo` objects. You should be able to disable this with:

```
class FooArchive < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.inheritance_column = nil
```

Note: untested. You may need to use a non-existing column instead of `nil` to make this work.

Comment: I test it and it works like

    ``class FooArchive < ActiveRecord::Base
      self.inheritance_column = :_type_disabled
    end``